# Не создаётся спрайт из Resources в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Создаю спрайт таким путем:

```
var ground = Resources.Load("GroundSprite");
Instantiate(ground, new Vector3(x + 0.5f, -1, -y - 0.5f),
            Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
```

путь к спрайту из Assets - "Assets\Resources\GroundSprite.png". После запуска ничего не происходит, ни ошибок ни предупреждений а самих спрайтов нет(они должны быть как много картинок на заднем фоне).
ground = GroundSprite (UnityEngine.Texture2D) это верно, я проверял(Debug.Log(...)). В Advanced settings спрайта включено чтение и запись.
Также я пробовал:

```
var ground = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("GroundSprite");
```

ничего не изменилось

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Вам нужно создать Папку Resources в ней папку Prefabs и в это пупку закинуть ваши картинки, по итогу Assets/Resources/Prefabs/
2. Resources.Load("Prefabs/GroundSprite");

Comment: Не помогает все также как и в прошлых случаях

Comment: @Morenci ну значит это твои уже проблемы, наши два варианта полностью рабочии